# Exporting spatial population density data to Excel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, excel, xy, population

I have spatial population density data that I would like to export to Excel (or similar) so that I can use it in analysis with another dataset. Specifically, I want the XY coordinates and the values in a table. The pop. dens data is a raster dataset, and I have tried converting it into integer form, then converting that to points, joining the points to the integer raster data, then getting the XY coordinates. I run into problems with the join, because the object ids in the raster file don't match those in the vector/point file...which was created from the raster file. I understand why not, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Any suggestions on how best to go about this? I suspect my dataset is too large for the sample command; I tried running it for 48 hours with no output.

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1 for desktop.

Edited to add that I have this problem regardless of whether I convert the raster data to points or to polygons (and then get the XY coordinates from the centroid of each polygon)

Comment: You can convert raster type float to points and calculate their coordinates. I suspect that much better way is to convert your other data to geometry and sample density raster

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to first and foremost convert your raster data to vector  using the Raster to Polygon (Conversion) tool prior to joining it to the other dataset and exporting to Excel.

Comment: This tool won't accept floating raster as input. Please post tested solution to avoid down votes

Comment: like i said in my original post, i have converted it from raster to vector. my problem is that in the conversion i end up with vector object ids that don't match up with the original raster object ids, so when i try to join the new vector dataset to the original raster to get the pop. density values, they don't match up.